# Is it possible to declare multiple routes for ASPNET.Core OData

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, odata

I'm using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.0.0 nuget package.

I've registered my OData route prefix like the following.

```
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
    var builder = new ModelODataBuilder();
    routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoutes", "odata/Route1", builder.GetEdmModel(app.ApplicationServices));
});
```

Each OData Controller has a ODataRoutePrefix where the prefix corresponds to an EntitySet declared and configured in the GetEdmModel. For example

`[ODataRoutePrefix("Service1")]`

However, I need some services to have a route prefix of "odata/Route1" while others have "odata/Route2". For example

http://odata/Route1/Service1
http://odata/Route2/Service2

I can't work out how to configure this. The following code does not work

```
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
    var builder = new ModelODataBuilder();
    routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute1", "odata/Route1", builder.GetEdmModelForRoute1(app.ApplicationServices));

    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute2", "odata/Route1", builder.GetEdmModelForRoute2(app.ApplicationServices));
});
```

Does anyone know how I would configure this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way.

added an extra app.UseMvc in my Startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc( b =>
        {
            b.Select( ).Expand( ).Filter( ).OrderBy( ).MaxTop( 100 ).Count( );
            b.MapODataServiceRoute( "odata" , "odata" , EdmModelBuilder.GetEdmModel( app.ApplicationServices ) );
        } );
        app.UseMvc( b =>
        {
            b.Select( ).Expand( ).Filter( ).OrderBy( ).MaxTop( 100 ).Count( );
            b.MapODataServiceRoute( "membership" , "membershipapi" , EdmModelBuilderMembership.GetEdmModel( app.ApplicationServices ) );
        } );
```

It has been working so far...

You would also have to change your code so that you are not using the same path in both mappings: "odata/Route1"